# PyGTK login panel wouldn't allow me login twice

Tags: python, pygtk

I have written a simple and yet basic interface for an imaginary DVD Shop for learning Python with PyGTK. The current stage is at writing a simple user center.

When you execute this file, the first "Login + Logout" is acting correctly, but when you decide to login the second time with same/different account, it behaved as if it's still logged out, but the "Login" button has been changed to "Logout".

Code has been truncated to what's needed.

Please help me, I am new to Python and PyGTK. Thanks.

File link: http://pastebin.com/eK7z7S48

Comment: It's more helpful if you paste the relevant code in the question.

Comment: I have truncated the code to pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to [overwriting a class variable with an instance variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

If you are setting `DVDshop.loggedIn` instead of `self.loggedIn` your code will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed my code not using a logout/login button in this window, instead, I create a new graphical login interface. Thanks for your help though :)